# Platform independent builds of conda packages

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to build a conda package containing a single Python package that reads static file on import. While the package itself works fine, the location of the package ends up depending on the platform used to build the package, so that it ends up being impossible to import the package on a platform different from what was used to build it.

Since there is nothing platform dependent going on at all, and since conda allows for cross-platform packages through `noarch`, it seems like it should be possible to build the package on a single platform, rather than once per platform.

Here's a minimal example:

**`/setup.py`**:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='mypackage',
    description='My platform independent package',
    packages=find_packages(),
    data_files=[('mypackage', ['mypackage/myfile.txt'])]
)
```

**`/conda_recipe/meta.yaml`**:

```
{% set data = load_setup_py_data() %}

build:
  noarch: python

package:
  name: mypackage

source:
  path: ..

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

about:
  summary: {{ data.get('description') }}
```

**`/mypackage/myfile.txt`**:

```
foo
```

**`/mypackage/__init__.py`**:

```
import os

# Print contents of myfile.txt when the package is imported
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myfile.txt')) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

By dropping the `noarch: python` section of `meta.yaml`, I can build packages that work on the platforms they are build on. However, if I build the `noarch` package using `conda build` on Windows, and `conda install` it on either platform, the Python module and data file end up in `{conda-env}/Lib/site-packages`, while if I build it on Linux, and `conda install` it on either platform, they end up in `{conda-env}/lib/python3.7/site-packages` (note the lowercase `l`).

This is an issue because the environment variables determining include paths differ on the two platforms. As a result, the package built on Windows works fine on Windows, and the package built on Linux works fine on Linux, but the package built on one platform won't run on the other platform; in particular, Miniconda on Linux by default includes the latter path in `sys.path`, so it won't be able to find the package built on Windows, installed on Linux.

That is, I can't simply build the package on one platform, dump it in `noarch` on my channel, and be happy, even though the package contents themselves are platform independent. Of course, the static data file isn't the culprit here, but I've included it in my problem regardless, simply because ensuring that those end up in the right place is non-trivial by itself.

The issue occurs when using the most recent versions of Miniconda on Windows and WSL.

So my question becomes:

> If I want to build a conda package containing nothing but a simple file, and an `__init__.py` reading this file when I import the package, can I get away with building the package on a single platform?

Comment: I would guess that you should never have to actually know the exact location where the file is stored, but get the path from python itself. This seems related: https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/packaging_pitfalls.html

Comment: Even Python wouldn't know where to look though: When the package is built on Windows, then installed on Linux, it ends up being placed in a location that's not on `sys.path`. It really is conda specific.

Comment: Is this at all helpful: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html? I.e., use the `__file__` value to determine the location of the `__init__.py`, which will be in `site-packages` for both platforms, then load the non-code file relative to that.

Comment: @merv Thanks for the reference; that's actually what I do as well (maybe I should spell out `__init__.py` with a non-trivial example). The thing is, the installed package will end up in a different `site-packages` folder depending on the platform that was used to build the package: `Lib/site-packages` if I build on Windows, and `lib/python3.7/site-packages` if I build on Linux/WSL.

Comment: Made the example slightly less trivial. Again, the data file might well just obfuscate the question; I just want to make sure that whatever the right solution is, it works with those as well.

Comment: Shouldn't there also be a `build:\n\t noarch: python` in the `meta.yaml`? As stated in [these docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/user-guide/tasks/pkgs/use-noarch-pkgs/) and as illustrated, for example, in [Conda Forge's boto3 recipe](https://github.com/conda-forge/boto3-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml#L20).

Comment: @merv: There should; I should have spelled out that that's what I tried when building with `noarch` as a target (otherwise it wouldn't end up in `noarch` at all, but would only be available in `windows-64` and `linux-64`). Let me spell this out in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating conda-build and Python on both Windows and Linux, I am no able longer to reproduce my issue; after installing, the packages will still end up in different directories: `lib/python3.8/site-packages` on Linux and `lib/site-packages` on Windows; rather curiously the `l` is now lowercase on Windows, which ends up not mattering due to Windows being Windows.

Unfortunately, this offers little insight into the original issue, but at least this should be enough to get started.

In particular, the following steps work on the minimal example included in my original question, using WSL to test a package built on Windows:

1. Create a new environment, `mypackage-build`, activate it, and run `conda install python conda-build`.
2. On Windows, build the package using `conda build conda_recipe`.
3. Without specifying anything else, the built package ends up in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mypackage-build\conda-bld` on my machine.
4. Deactivate the build environment, create a new environment called `mypackage-test`, activate it, install Python, and install the package built above using `conda install -c C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mypackage-build\conda-bld mypackage`.
5. Run `where python` to ensure that `python.exe` is being picked up from the `mypackage-test` environment, run Python, call `import mypackage`, and note that the package is indeed imported.
6. On WSL, create a new environment called `mypackage-test-wsl`, activate it, install Python, and run `conda install -c /mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/miniconda3/envs/mypackage-build/conda-bld mypackage` (modified accordingly, if drives are mounted differently).
7. Run Python, `import mypackage`, and note that everything works (which is where I initially had run into issues).
8. Mirror the process, build the package on WSL, install it on Windows, and note that everything works.

I did run into one gotcha while testing the above, so let me note this here for completeness: When first creating `mypackage-test`, I had done so from the `mypackage-build` environment. As a result, even though packages would be installed in `mypackage-test`, the Python runtime from the parent environment would take precedence (which I think is weird, but okay), which would cause "step 5" above to fail;

```
>where python
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mypackage-build\python.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mypackage-build\envs\mypackage-test\python.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\python.exe
```